# Why didn't "Father" use the same anti-aging treatment as Kellog?

Tags: fallout

When we first see Conrad Kellog, one of the main antagonists in "Fallout 4", he doesn't look past 40, while Shaun is just an infant. When we see both of them again, Kellog looks just like before, even though we know that he is about 108 years old (he was about 10 when NCR was created), but "Father" looks like an old man.

Why didn't "Father" use the same process halting his own aging?

Comment: I don't have a convenient save to go back and read the terminals and thus post a comprehensive answer, but IIRC Father disliked the cyber-augmentation program and thus shut it down when he became director.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shaun believed cybernetics would not accomplish the Institute's goal of preserving humanity. He shut the project down before the goals of the lead scientist could gain widespread support.

From his 'personal notes' on his terminal:

> I'm told Kellogg has gone offline. Strangely, I find myself thinking of Dr. Walker. He had such high hopes for Kellogg. Such faith in the implants, and what they could mean. I still regret eliminating that project, but I know where it would have led us. Walker was never shy about his goals, and too many others were starting to listen. In the end, I believe I was justified. **The Institute is about preserving humanity, not some bizarre amalgamation of biology and technology.**